# multi level table row expand collapse react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multi level array of object, so if key value is object, then add expand/collapse button, and on click of it, render rows and so on...

```
var cars = {
  label: 'Autos',
  subs: [
    {
      label: 'SUVs',
      subs: []
    },
    {
      label: 'Trucks',
      subs: [
        {
          label: '2 Wheel Drive',
          subs: []
        },
        {
          label: '4 Wheel Drive',
          subs: [
            {
              label: 'Ford',
              subs: []
            },
            {
              label: 'Chevrolet',
              subs: []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: 'Sedan',
      subs: []
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I'm not quite sure how we could help you, as your post doesn't have any type of question. Is there an error? are you asking how to do it and if so then what resources have you looked at previously? The more useful information you provide the better we could help.

Comment: i refered this example - https://react-hooks-dynamically-add-table-row-expand-collapse.stackblitz.io, but on click of show, i need to open another row and this row also would have show button, on click of it, show another row.     basically need multi level table row expand collapse

Answer (score 0):

I created a demo for you using reactjs and recursion around your given object.

[codesandbox-demo](https://720d8.csb.app/)

Have a look at it, if it helps in your use case. you can refer the below code to infer more

```
import React from "react";

const cars = {
  label: "Autos",
  subs: [
    {
      label: "SUVs",
      subs: []
    },
    {
      label: "Trucks",
      subs: [
        {
          label: "2 Wheel Drive",
          subs: []
        },
        {
          label: "4 Wheel Drive",
          subs: [
            {
              label: "Ford",
              subs: []
            },
            {
              label: "Chevrolet",
              subs: []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: "Sedan",
      subs: []
    }
  ]
};

const generateRow = (rowData, open, setOpen) => {
  const handleExpand = () => {
    let set = new Set(open);
    set.add(rowData.label);
    setOpen(set);
  };

  const handleCollapse = () => {
    let set = new Set(open);
    set.delete(rowData.label);
    setOpen(set);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        {rowData.label}
        &nbsp;
        {rowData.subs.length > 0 && !open.has(rowData.label) && (
          <button onClick={handleExpand}>&#x2193;</button>
        )}
        {rowData.subs.length > 0 && open.has(rowData.label) && (
          <button onClick={handleCollapse}>&#x2191;</button>
        )}
      </p>
      {rowData.subs.length > 0 && open.has(rowData.label) && (
        <ul>
          {rowData.subs.map((child) => {
            return (
              <li key={child.label}>{generateRow(child, open, setOpen)}</li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      )}
      <ol></ol>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  // open state to keep trach of which labels are selected to be open or not
  // use recursion to generate list on demand

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(new Set());

  return generateRow(cars, open, setOpen);
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I need it in table format
means all keys would be table header 
and their values would be in table body with expand/collapse feature

i've updated  Array here , mine is like this for table https://codesandbox.io/s/so-p3-forked-my423?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The idea of table header and body is ambiguous. i would suggest you to create a sample ui layout of your desired output. then we can try to work out a solution